# XCode 4.2 - running 4.1 simulator

Tags: xcode4.2

How can I run iOS 4.1 simulator from XCode 4.2?

So from "more simulator", I installed "iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support", what is that? Is that supposed to allow me to run my program in a 4.1 simulator? Doesn't seem to have an option from the dropdown to run the app in 4.1.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: I believe it's the SDK, so you can compile it under that iOS SDK. But I imagine the debugging part would involve running it in the simulator.

Comment: Alas, no: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14128/how-do-i-install-the-3-0-iphone-simulator-on-xcode-4

Answer (score 0):

You need to iOS5 or at lest iOS 4.3 
Also, you will update your source  because there are new functions and a lot of changes in this version.

Don't worry, 4.2 version is better.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1 **how to get the 4.1 simulator**

Following this post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31412/how-can-i-install-iphone-simulator-4-2-on-xcode-4-2

1. Goto apple website https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
2. download "Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3 for Snow Leopard"
3. mound the disk image (double click the file downloaded)
4. From the terminal run

   open /Volumes/Xcode\ and\ iOS\ SDK/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDK4_1.pkg

Question #2 **What is Device Debugging Support**

To plug in a device, deploy the app on a device, and debug on that device you need device debugging support. Otherwise you get a message that says the device is not supported. Even if you can run the 4.1 simulator, you would not be able to debug on a device without that.

PS: you also need to pay the $100 per year to debug on a device.